# How can Error in flutter stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, statelesswidget

I have a problem in flutter in main.dart page in Stateless widget inside return MyApp( the title: , home: , debugShowCheckedModeBanner:
and routes they give me an error "The named parameter 'title /any of them' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing nameed parameter with the name'

class MyApp extends Statelesswidget { @override Widget buil(BuildContext context) { return MyApp( title : 'page', . . ... ); } }

Comment: post your full code

Answer (score 0):

Stateless Widget does not have title and other parameters, those parameters belongs to MaterialApp widget
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html

Comment: Thank tou very much

Comment: It is often necessary to place code for greater understanding

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `MaterialApp` inside the build method of MyApp class.
And then MaterialApp have property `title`, `debugShowCheckedModeBanner`, and `routes`.

[image]